# macbook cannot access google sites but only if using WEP

Tags: wireless-networking, wep

It's the weirdest networking puzzle I've ever encountered...

I have a working Wifi network using a Netgear WGR614 router. It's configured with WEP authentication. 4 linux computers, two iphones and one Android all have no problem using the network.

Yesterday I tried connecting a macbook air.

Firefox and safari browsers connects to everything fine EXCEPT any google site, including www.google.com or any site using google analytics.

I can telnet on port 80 to www.google.com. I can ping google.com, but neither browser will connect to any google site.

Yet, if I turn WEP off, the browsers can connect!

Very weird. The netgear router isn't blocking anything, as far as I can determine. DNS for the google sites appears to be fine. traceroute to various google sites succeeds.

Comment: Does it connect if use a LAN cable from Mac to router (leaving WEP on in the router)

Comment: Yes, it does. If I connect a LAN cable, leaving everything else unchanged, I can access google sites in the browsers.