# Cannot access Google sites with my wireless connection

Tags: wireless-networking, router

I have a problem where I am not able to access most Google sites. This includes google.com, Google analytics, Google docs, and even YouTube. This is the case for all browsers (Chrome, IE, Firefox). I am able to access Gmail, but only on Chrome (maybe because I was already logged on when the problem began?)

I am able to access all other sites. However, they never load Google Analytics.

This problem only occurs when I am connected via my wireless router. It works fine with a cable. It also works fine on other wireless networks. Other devices work fine with my wireless connection. So it's the combination of my PC and my router.

I have tried flushing the dns with >ipconfig /flushdns. And restarting my computer. And turning the router off and back on.

I am using the Netgear router (genie WNR612v3). I have seen one other problem similar this, [macbook cannot access google sites but only if using WEP](https://superuser.com/questions/596365/macbook-cannot-access-google-sites-but-only-if-using-wep), but there was no solution. Unlike that person's case, however, I still cannot access Google sites when I turn the router's security off. Also, I have a PC with Windows 7.

Please help me; I'm using bing.

Comment: possible duplicate of [I can't open google-related sites](http://superuser.com/questions/679454/i-cant-open-google-related-sites)

Comment: Can you elaborate on "can't access"?  What are the exact symptoms?  Is your problem similar to what is described in the proposed duplicate question?

Answer (score 0):

If you try to use Netgear's website yourself, it seems to insist there are no firmware updates for the WNR612v3. But if you use Google (sorry) to search it, you find several firmware updates including this one for v1.0.0.18 from a few months ago: http://kb.netgear.com/app/answers/detail/a_id/23764

Get this version onto your box to make sure you're not fighting an issue they've already fixed.